# Union of Cliques in an Undirected Graph

Tags: graph-theory

Is it true that any undirected graph is a union of maximal cliques? 
Since an edge is a size 2 clique?

Comment: It seems obvious for finite graphs. I think that cliques satisfy Zorn's lemme, so in particular, every edge is in a maximal clique in the infinite case, too.